# Magento - Add node and save module config

Tags: php, magento, simplexml, config, adminhtml

I try to add a node to the module config like this:

```
$model = Mage::getConfig()->getModuleConfig('lemike_devmode');
$model->setNode('foo/bar/baz', 'qux', true /* overwrite */);
var_dump($model); // empty Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element
```

But it does not create the new nodes. The `$model` is just empty.

What went wrong here?

After that I guess `Mage::getConfig()->saveCached()` is correct for saving the new node, or?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish, are you trying to add a variable to core_config_data, or register a module node? The "foo/bar/baz" format suggests you're trying the former, but the methods suggest the latter.

Comment: I like to register a module node as shown in the first snippet.

Comment: You may want to read [Alan Storms Guide On Loading Declared Modules](http://alanstorm.com/magento_config_declared_modules_tutorial). In it he goes over the process that Magento handles automatically to load modules. The module is registered in what would be your `app/etc/modules/Lemike_Devmode.xml` file, and Magento will pull your default configuration settings from `app/code/local/Lemike/Devmode/etc/system.xml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If is more easy to you, you could try with custom variables.

Hope it helps. [The official Doc](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/creating-custom-variables)

Greetings.